# Why this borrowing error if I'm using `&self` in this function?

Tags: rust

I have this code ([PLAYGROUND HERE](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e5bd17279f811f8fb20063dcc5bb87ea)):

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Default, Clone)]
pub struct BaseFile {
    pub id: Option<String>,
    pub location: String,
    pub size: u64,
}

impl BaseFile {
    pub fn filename(&self) -> String {
        "CALCULATED_FILENAME".to_string()
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, Default, Clone)]
pub struct AdvancedFile {
    pub id: Option<String>,
    pub filename: String,
    pub size: u64,
}

impl AdvancedFile {
    pub fn from_base(
        id: Option<String>,
        filename: String,
        size: u64,
    ) -> Self {
        Self {
            id,
            filename,
            size,
        }
    }
}

impl From<BaseFile> for AdvancedFile {
    fn from(base_file: BaseFile) -> Self {
        Self::from_base(
            base_file.id,
            base_file.filename(),
            base_file.size,
        )
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let domain_file = BaseFile {
        id: None,
        location: "new_location".to_string(),
        size: 123,
    };

    dbg!(domain_file);
}
```

with this error:

```
error[E0382]: borrow of partially moved value: `base_file`
  --> src/main.rs:39:13
   |
38 |             base_file.id,
   |             ------------ value partially moved here
39 |             base_file.filename(),
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ value borrowed here after partial move
   |
   = note: partial move occurs because `base_file.id` has type `Option<String>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

Why this error if I'm using `&self` in `pub fn filename(&self) -> String {`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since that object is being ripped apart and reassembled, you may need to capture the parts before you do that:

```rust
// Capture any values that depend on `base_name` being intact
let filename = base_name.filename();

Self::from_base(
    base_file.id,
    filename,
    base_file.size,
)
```